# Cannot read file just written to

Tags: java, android, file-io

I am trying to read from a file to which some user credentials were written. I want to write the file to an internal storage location. The code:

```
 private void writeSendDetails(String name, String number, String emailID) {

        //This function writes details to userCredentials.txt and also sends it to server.
        String text = "Name: " + userName + "\n" + "Number: " + userNumber + "\n" + "Email ID:" + userEmailID;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(userCredFile, MODE_PRIVATE);
            Log.v(this.toString(), fos.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(fos != null) {
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
            try {
                osw.write(text);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.v(this.toString(), "IOException caught in osw.write");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                osw.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                osw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Log.v(this.toString(), "Written everything to userCredentials.txt");
        readUserCredentials();
        //code to send to server should begin here.

    }

private void readUserCredentials() {
        //function to read name, number and email ID from userCredentials.txt
        /* Steps:
         * 1. Check if file exists.
         * 2. If it does, read all relevant credentials.
         */

        File f = new File(userCredFile);
        if(f.canRead()) {
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Can open userCredentials for reading from.");
        }

        try {
            FileReader fis = new FileReader(f);
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Wrapping a buffered reader around file reader.");
            BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(fis, 100);
            String line;
            try {
                while((line = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Line read = " + line);
                    line = bufRead.readLine();
                    if(line.indexOf("Name: ") != -1) {
                        Log.v(this.toString(), "Found name in the string.");
                        userName = line.substring(6);
                    } else if(line.indexOf("Number: ") != -1) {
                        Log.v(this.toString(), "Found number in the string.");
                        userNumber = line.substring(8);
                    } else if(line.indexOf("Email ID: ") != -1) {
                        Log.v(this.toString(), "Found email in the string.");
                        userEmailID = line.substring(10);
                    }
                }
                Log.v(this.toString(), "User credentials = " + userName + "   " + userNumber + "    " + userEmailID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v(this.toString(), "IOException caught.");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            Log.v(this.toString(), "File not found for reading.");
        }
    }
```

The `LogCat` output shows:

```
04-14 15:20:43.789: V/com.sriram.htmldisplay.htmlDisplay@44c0c660(675): Written everything to userCredentials.txt
04-14 15:20:43.789: V/com.sriram.htmldisplay.htmlDisplay@44c0c660(675): File not found for reading.
04-14 15:20:43.889: V/com.sriram.htmldisplay.fireflymenu@44c401e0(675): File not found for reading.
```

My question(s):
1. I need to write the file to internal storage. Am I doing it correctly?
2. Why is the file just written not being read?

Comment: you have a lot of these: `printStackTrace()` which may be hiding the actuall fault, `Log.e()` these errors to see if the file is actually being written to. my guess is its not found during the write as well.

Comment: the `printStackTrace()` is part of the auto-implemented stub that Eclipse generates.

Comment: no exceptions are caught in the write.

Comment: Just because Eclipse generates them, it doesn't mean that `printStackTrace()` is the right thing to do there.

Answer (score 1):

Some things for your code:

1. @Oren is correct, you should use `Log.e(TAG, "message", e)` instead of the auto-created stuff from eclipse!
2. you should simply merge the 3 try/catch to one. No need to make it 3 times...
3. you should use `Log.e()` as said above for your `FileNotFoundException` too, so see the stacktrace to check the real reason (which currently covers the hint to solve your issue)

If you would have done at least number 3, you would have seen that the file you try to read could not be found. Thats why your log doesn't show the `Can open userCredentials for reading from.` output from your if statement.

The reason for that is pretty simple: You create the file by using `openFileOutput(userCredFile, MODE_PRIVATE);`. If you read the [documentation of openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) you will stumble upon:

> The name of the file to open; can not contain path separators.

That means that `userCredFile` can only be something like `test.txt`. Also this method creates a file in a directory that can't be easily access from "outside".

When you now try to read the file via `FileReader(userCredFile)` it should be obvious, that android will try to open it in the root directory: `/text.txt` and it will, of course, fail. No non-root app can write/read in the root directory.

The main question, and also the answer to your issue: Why don't you use the corresponding `openFileInput(userCredFile)` method to read the file?